# URL Encoding Issue with "Œ"

Tags: java, http, urlencode

I have read all of the Java URL encoding threads on here but still haven't found a solution to my problem:  Google Chrome encodes "BŒUF" to "B%8CUF" POST data, awesome.  How can I convince Java to do the same?  (The website is `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr">` and `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">` in case this is important.)

```
System.out.println(URLEncoder.encode("BŒUF", "utf-8"));
System.out.println(URLEncoder.encode("BŒUF", "iso-8859-1"));
System.out.println(URLEncoder.encode("BŒUF", "iso-8859-15"));
System.out.println(new URI("http","www.google.com","/ig/api","BŒUF", null).toASCIIString());
```

prints

```
B%C5%92UF
B%3FUF
B%BCUF
http://www.google.com/ig/api?B%C5%92UF
```

but not "B%8CUF"?

Comment: According to utf-8 encoding, it is correct. Œ translates to c5 92 in hex. Please check: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=256&unicodeinhtml=hex and search for Œ

Comment: The problem you need to solve is Chrome using ISO-8859-*, not Java using UTF-8. You may want to check the HTML spec for form encoding issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifically looking for `windows-1252` encoding ***not*** `UTF-8`:

```
System.out.println(URLEncoder.encode("BŒUF", "windows-1252"));
```

Gives,

```
B%8CUF
```

Comment: Ascii should url encodes too %8c as well so you could give that a go. http://www.backbone.se/urlencodingUTF8.htm

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for ... can't believe I asked earlier ... thanks a ton!  :D

Comment: @lalaland: Œ is not even 'normal' extended ascii (latin-1), but latin-9